How to enable ICS for my events. I am adding events via calendar.addEvent on fullcalendar
How to enable ICS for my events via JS / HTML / CSS. I am adding events via calendar.addEvent on fullcalendar
I tried the below -
https://rentalbookingsoftware.com/adding-icalendar-or-ics-export-to-fullcalendar/
But seems in that case I need to add event via their way which I do not want to. I am already able to add events via calendar.addEvent.

Why would you want to? If you want to provide an iCalendar feed for your calendar it would probably make more sense to do that server-side (unless perhaps your fullCalendar is displaying data aggregated from a number of different external sources, and you want to bring them all together in a single ics file.

Or, are you wanting to just output an ICS file individually for each separate event in the calendar? You didn't clarify the use case.

I need to add event via their way which I do not want to...their approach does not affect how you add events into fullCalendar. The code shown demonstrates how to add events to the ICS file. It takes event data from a JavaScript array. You can feed the ics() object any JS object you like - whether that comes from an export from fullCalendar or anywhere else, it really doesn't matter. There's actually no direct dependency on fullCalendar here at all. So what exactly is the issue and the usage scenario you're trying to address? What really is the actual problem here?
